# How to make the row of repeater slideable using enyo.js?

Tags: enyo

I have a repeater .On which intap I am giving a method.Like that I want to give different method onswipe of each row.

```
{kind: "Scroller",classes:"enyo.fit",touch:true,style: "width: 314px; height:380px;",components: [
{kind: "Repeater", onSetupItem:"setupItem", components: [
        {name:"item",classes:"repeaterdesign" ,components: [
            {tag:"span", name: "DetailName",ontap: "tapped"}
        ]}
    ]} 
]},
```

In the above In repeater I have given **ontap: "tapped"** .Now I want onswipe.both I want in this repeater.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Enyo 2.0, the repeater doesn't support swipeable rows.  You could take a look at prepareRow/LockRow in the List implementation if you wanted to try to create your own.  You can also take a look at the Enyo 1.0 source to see how swipeable rows were implemented.

Update: There is a swipeableItem in the WIP package.  It's not quite 'production ready' but you can try it out and see if it works for your needs.